# Unable create TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-tablayout

I'm using android studio 2.1.1 and trying to create a TabLayout. When I'm trying

```
import  android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
```

Tablayout is highlighted and it says Can't resolve symbol TabLayout as shown in the screenshot below.[image: Can't resolve symbol TabLayout]

I have all the SDK set up properly and other things seems to be fine. Even developer docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) mentions the TabLayout in the same package as I'm trying to import.(Auto Import didn't work) Any clue as to what might be wrong.
Even the co-ordinator layout doesn't work. Please let me know whats going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall import the design support library first in your `app.gradle` under dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

Comment: oh yeah. Such a silly mistake. ashamed of myself. Thank you.